# Libgdx file handle.. reading a single line

Tags: java, libgdx, save, load, filehandle

I am trying to save and load files on a project that is coded on libgdx. Which means that i cant use a buffered reader because android wont read it.. and i cant move the project to android because it has to be in the core... after days and days or understanding all.. now i am trying File handing which should work right?? but i cant get it to read line by line.. it puts all the text in on string.. Help plzz.. also is my understanding correct and saving and loading is waaaay more complicated than it should be??  here is the code..

```
  FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.local("words.txt");
  String text = handle.readString();
  words.add(text);
```

Comment: words is a String Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to read this line by line. When your reading a file in using the LibGDX FileHandle API which include strings, byte arrays and into various readers; there are several ways to read the data in. I am assuming you have some form of dictionary in this file, with the words in a list separated by newlines? If this is the case you can take your existing string and split on the new line terminator.

```
  FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.local("words.txt");
  String text = handle.readString();
  String wordsArray[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
  for(String word : wordsArray) {
      words.add(word);
  }
```

There's only really two newlines (UNIX and Windows) that you need to worry about.

[FileHandle API](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html)

Comment: it is .. and i am trying to split them.. let me try it and mark if it works

Answer (score 0):

This is to all of you out there new to saving and loading and tired of looking for answers.. let me save u the trouble and days of research...

If you start a project in libgdx and want to save load on android.. Do not follow the buffered reader or inputstreamer or any of these tutorials THEY WILL NOT WORK because for some reason android cannot read inside the assest folder.. it will work on ur desktop version only..

if you are using android studios alone then go ahead with the try catch buffered or file or inputstreamer..

Also the Context.. asset manager.. and that route WILL NOT WORK because the project has to be in your android folder not core to use these libraries..

ELSE FOLLOW THE ABOVE METHOD..

classpath.. internal.. external .. or local ... depending on where you store ur file!!!.. your welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
String str ="";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();            
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("text.txt");
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.read()));
            if (is != null) {                            
                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
                    buf.append(str + "\n" );
                }                
            }
        } finally {
            try { is.close(); } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
        }
```